# Does Zelda: Skyward Sword require the Wii MotionPlus accessory?

Tags: zelda-skyward-sword

Or will MotionPlus be optional?

Just wondering if I'll be required to buy this accessory for this game.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, the MotionPlus will be necessary for Skyward Sword, and the reason is because we'll need the increased sensitivity to wield the remote as the sword.

http://www.zelda.com/skywardsword/#/about/wii-remote-plus-technology

Comment: The Gold Wiimote edition of the game has the Wii Motion+ bundled.

Comment: As do most of the controllers sold these days.